# neo4j model a time-varying graph

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to find the best way to model time varying graph in neo4j. The current model use a time variable "year" in the relationship to capture the time. For example,

(A)-[year:2000]->(B)-[year:2000]->(C)

(A)-[year:2000]->(D)-[value:2000]->(E)

(A)-[year:1999]->(B)-[year:1999]->(C)

(A)-[year:1999]->(D)

```
CREATE (a:firm {name:'A'}), (b:firm {name:'B'}), (c:firm {name:'C'}), 
(d:firm {name:'D'}), (e:firm {name:'E'}),
(a)-[:REL {year: 2000}]->(b)->[:REL {year: 2000}]->(c),
(a)-[:REL {year: 2000}]->(d)->[:REL {year: 2000}]->(e),
(a)-[:REL {year: 1999}]->(b)->[:REL {year: 1999}]->(c),
(a)-[:REL {year: 1999}]->(d);
```

We are modeling this way because the original database stores the bilateral relationship by year. This is definitely not a space-efficient way to store a time varying graph. If space is not our concern, is this a reasonable way to model a time varying graph?

In this case, is it possible to get the difference between two years, i.e., (D)-[value:2000]->(E)?

(I have read [Neo4j time dependent graph model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088815/neo4j-time-dependent-graph-model) but it seems outdated.)

Comment: you could also store the year as relationship type instead of relationship property, should be more performant AFAIK. WDYM with the difference?

Comment: @TomažBratanič Thanks. How does the relationship type differ from relationship property in terms of performance? The difference between 1999 and 2000 is the relationship (D)-[value:2000]->(E). What is the proper cypher query for this?